# update existing cart via ajax creates new cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Running craft cms 2 as a backend with react as the front end I am able to create a cart via an ajax post request to `actions/commerce/cart/updateCart`.

However, I'm not sure how to then update that cart. Every request to `updateCart` creates a new cart.

What do I need to pass to `updateCart` for it to update instead of create a new cart?

Comment: Turns out it was a lot simpler than I thought.

forgot to add `credentials: 'same-origin',` to the fetch object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Craft 3

This is how Craft Commerce fetches the Card

```
if ($orderNumber = $request->getBodyParam('orderNumber')) {
    // Get the cart from the order number
    $cart = Order::find()->number($orderNumber)->isCompleted(false)->one();
}
```

You have to include an `orderNumber` parameter

#### Craft 2

```
$number = $this->_getSessionCartNumber();

if ($cart = $this->_getCartRecordByNumber($number))
{
    $this->_cart = Commerce_OrderModel::populateModel($cart);
}
else
{
    $this->_cart = new Commerce_OrderModel;
    $this->_cart->number = $number;
}

/**
 * @return mixed|string
 */
private function _getSessionCartNumber()
{
    $cookieId = $this->cookieCartId;
    $cartNumber = craft()->userSession->getStateCookieValue($cookieId);

    if (!$cartNumber)
    {
        $cartNumber = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $configInterval = craft()->config->get('cartCookieDuration', 'commerce');
        $interval = new DateInterval($configInterval);
        $cartExpiry = date_create('@0')->add($interval)->getTimestamp();
        craft()->userSession->saveCookie($cookieId, $cartNumber, $cartExpiry);
    }

    return $cartNumber;
}
```

I think you'll have to change the cookie